# Indesign-exported PDF selecting text in wrong order?

Tags: adobe-indesign

**Edit:** Someone else recently posted about something similar, but there were no solutions. I posted this because I cannot yet comment or upvote that other thread, and want to give more context to the issue!

I made a 2-column resume in Indesign, with different text frames for each different title/heading/collection of bullet points. When I highlight or select the text on the Adobe PDF I've exported (no changes in settings), it selects everything out of order.

I blurred out the text bc it's not necessary, but in the picture below I clicked & dragged over just the red highlighted part, and it highlighted those other parts, too. That's the problem I'm having.

[image]

Copy & pasting the whole document to a Google Doc causes everything to be out of order, as well.

Currently, the PDF has the following:

- Text threading
- Putting each text layer in order of desired
  highlighting order (top to bottom, left to right)
- Grouping text by layer per column

I found a couple other people with a similar problem, but no solution was found. Not sure if anyone knows how to fix this or has experienced this same thing.

Thank you!